# How to split an object that have dates, in another object, separating by year and month?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I'm trying to split one collection of objects in javascript by year and month, into different objects.

Can someone point me in the correct direction of how to deal with this kind of problem?

The data i get from the api:

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
ano: "2020"
comprovante: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dspsas-d0668.appspot.com/o/Storage%2FUser%2FbkrxhlxOCtY3kHUHlW9lnStIVlG2%2FComprovantes%2FxToy7.png?alt=media&token=d2184d68-f094-4c68-8a04-8c5e8e864559"
created_at: FirestoreTimestamp {_seconds: 1598723129, _nanoseconds: 75000000}
dataLancamento: FirestoreTimestamp {_seconds: 1598670000, _nanoseconds: 0}
dateArray: (3) ["29", "08", "2020"]
descricao: "lançamento"
dia: "29"
id: "3HCE8VxzBlV7GKsu89Ti"
mes: "08"
tags: (3) ["Tag", "teste", "Música"]
tipoLancamento: "Despesa"
user_id: "bkrxhlxOCtY3kHUHlW9lnStIVlG2"
valor: 1
__proto__: Object
1:
ano: "2020"
comprovante: null
created_at: FirestoreTimestamp {_seconds: 1598809946, _nanoseconds: 737000000}
dataLancamento: FirestoreTimestamp {_seconds: 1588302000, _nanoseconds: 0}
dateArray: (3) ["01", "05", "2020"]
descricao: "Teste"
dia: "01"
id: "EBHCwuc4w7Yum5H20C6u"
mes: "05"
tags: false
tipoLancamento: "Despesa"
user_id: "bkrxhlxOCtY3kHUHlW9lnStIVlG2"
valor: 5
__proto__: Object
2: {comprovante: null, valor: 1, created_at: FirestoreTimestamp, dataLancamento: FirestoreTimestamp, tipoLancamento: "Entrada", …}
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
object:
{
    0: {
        year: 2019,
        months: {
            0: {...obj}
            1: {...obj}
            2: {
                month: 'mar',
                items: {
                    0: {...item},
                    1: {...item},
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.B logging from mobile so formatting and syntax maybe a little incorrect. Also it seems you are unfamiliar with js objects and arrays so will keep it simple so that you may understand what is happening.

```
const yourArray = [
   { ...dateArray: [...]},
   { ...dateArray: [...]},
   { ...dateArray: [...]}
];

var monthNames = [‘January’...];

function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
       return objectArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
      const year = obj[property][2];
      if (!acc[year]) {
         acc[year] = [];
      }
      var month = monthNames[obj[property][1]];
      if(!acc[year][month]){
          acc[year][month] = [];
      }
      // Add object to list for given key's value
      acc[year][month].push(obj);
      return acc;
   }, {});
}
const grouped = groupBy(yourArray, 'dateArray');
console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Hi @lucasPacheco did you find this answer helpful? do you have any questions about it?

Comment: I finished a full day's work and i just began to try to implement your suggestion. With a few modifications to adapt to my situation it worked perfectly!

Thank you very much!